# How to use Closure as an Anonymous Function like on Javascript?

Tags: php, class, static, closures

I have a question, I didn't clearly understand what Closures uses on OOP, but I did something like this:

```
<?php /** * */ 
class Xsample {
public static $name; 
public static $address = array("Mandaluyong", "City"); 
public static function setName ($name) {
self::$name = $name; 
} 
public static function getName() {
echo self::$name; 
} 
public static function sub ($func) {
return call_user_func_array($func, self::$address); 
} 
} 
Xsample::setName("Eric"); 
Xsample::sub(function ($address) {
echo $address; 
}); 
?>
```

and it echo "Mandaluyong".
I'm expecting that it'll return an array from Xsample::$address but it didn't. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: note the difference between call_user_func and call_user_func_array. sounds like you're expecting the behavior of call_user_func

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call_user_func_array` passes the 2nd argument's elements as paramters to the function being called. so if your function had another parameter it will work.

```
Xsample::sub(function ($address, $address2) {
echo $address; 
echo $address2; 
});
```